# Stop duplicating start of row data in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, logic

I am building a database for a local automobile dealership.

The client wants a drill down option for locating service plans and I am trying to work out the logic.

So basically the first thing the user does is select the vehicle model then the year the transmission and then the KM’s / Miles (This data is used to locate the service plan):

[image]

This is done via drop down menus populated with values from the database.

Now the service plan pricing per task changes dependant on the KM’s / Miles and is never the same between vehicles.

So visually it looks like this:

[image]

So the first 4 columns (Model, Year, Transmission, KM’s) are the values for the drop downs and its these values that determine which service plan to use (and yes some vehicle names repeat due to having either automatic or manual transmission as demonstrated in above table - and I will need to make sure they do not repeat in the drop downs).

Now what I am wondering is how do I lay this out in MySQL to work with a PHP query would I

fill all the blank cells with duplicate data e.g

[image]

**or**

Use normalisation somehow (somebody suggested this to me) unfortunately I am new to databases and not quite sure how to work this, I realise it means having smaller relational tables but I don’t quite understand the logic.

Comment: How you have stored the data in db... Do you have 2 diff tables or a more then that.... What are the key fields in the tables...

Comment: I haven't created it yet I am trying to figure how to structure it before I start.

Comment: By looking at your table, I can say you should make two tables: `Sr.No. -> Model -> Year -> Transmission` and other as ` Sr. No -> KMs/Miles -> Oil...etc.`. Then you will have to map both tables with sr.no (Index field).

Comment: Okay @Ankur140290 that sounds like what I am looking for, could you possibly elaborate a bit more?

Comment: When user will say suppose `Vehicle-1 1996 Automatic` then you have to get the sr.no. from first table and then search second table with the same sr.no.

Comment: Okay that sounds good :) but the service plan changes for every single vehicle dependant on KM's? so how would I know which service plan to point it to?

Comment: You can either take KMs to the first table (This will make repetative entries...Not recomemded) OR You already have sr.no. so query with srno and KMS value in the second table

Comment: Sorry what is smo (still learning).

Comment: Sorry... That was Sr. No. It looked joined as i typed srno

Comment: Okay now I am following, do you mind if I open a chat to discuss this a bit further I just want to clarify a few things?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46133/discussion-between-otis-wright-and-ankur140290)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have table as shown below:

[image]

So as explained to you you can write query to extract your required data.

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested you need to Normalize your database if you want it to ever have data integrity and be able to adapt to change. You want to strive for AT LEAST 3rd Normal Form (3NF)

Start understanding Normalization because you will have a hard time building a good database without it. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

You will at least need to separate this into two tables. I would suggest a `Vehicle` table that contains a column for `Model`, `Year`, `Transmission`, `KM/Miles` (all the Vehicles attributes) and then a `Service Plan` table that has the Service plan attributes. The `Vehicle` table will probably then have a column for service plan that has a foreign key constraint on it that maps to the Primary Key of the `Service Plan` table (`Service_Plan_ID`). That way when you ask for vehicle X you will get a mapping to which service plan that vehicle is mapped to.

Comment: because KM's is what determines which service plans to use would I possibly put it on the service plans table?

Comment: No absolutely not. You aren't doing logic in the Database. You simply are creating an Entity and storing attributes about that entity. A vehicle has KM/Miles on it. Not the service plan.

Comment: Part of normalization is that every column on a table should be something that describes that entity

Comment: Okay I get that :) but like each vehicle has 8 service plans each one different than the last and dependant on KM's so how would I know where to point it?

Comment: If you have a many-to-many relationship between vehicles and service plans then I suggest another table that would be a mapping table (VehicleServicePlan) that contains an identity row and then foreign key rows for the VehicleId and ServicePlanId.

Comment: You are not undersanding what makes a vehicle unique. If it is has a model type of vehicle-1 and it has 10000 miles on it and there is another row with model type of vehicle-1 but has 20000 miles on it then this is a different vehicle entity even though it has the same model type.